# Diffrence between two Objects and add missing values

Tags: javascript

How to check diffrence between two Objects and add missing values?

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/aca0hdv9/

```
 var defaultOptions = {
         monit : {
            map:{
                googleMap: false
            },
            vehiclesList: {
                rightSide: false,
                number: true,
                driver: true,
                note: true,
            },
            vehicleCloud: {
                speed: true,
                date: true,
                alarms: true,
                fuelsCloud: true
            },
            driverCloud: true
     };

var userCacheOptions = {
        monit : {
                // Missing map options
            vehiclesList: {
                rightSide: false,
                number: false,
                driver: false
                // Missing note option
            },
            vehicleCloud: {
                speed: true,
                date: true,
                alarms: true,
                fuelsCloud: true
            },
            // Missing driverCloud option
         }
    };
```

I don't want to assign default values, i just want add **missing** values. Any idea how to do this in the least complicated way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get all ennumerable keys. From there, you simply have to iterate over them.

```js
var defaultOptions = {
  monit: {
    map: {
      googleMap: false
    },
    vehiclesList: {
      rightSide: false,
      number: true,
      driver: true,
      note: true,
    },
    vehicleCloud: {
      speed: true,
      date: true,
      alarms: true,
      fuelsCloud: true
    },
    driverCloud: true
  }
};

var userCacheOptions = {
  monit: {
    // Missing map options
    vehiclesList: {
      rightSide: false,
      number: false,
      driver: false
        // Missing note option
    },
    vehicleCloud: {
      speed: true,
      date: true,
      alarms: true,
      fuelsCloud: true
    }
    // Missing driverCloud option
  }
};

function fillBlanks(receiver, giver) {
  var receiverkeys = Object.keys(receiver);
  var giverkeys = Object.keys(giver);
  for(var i = 0; i < giverkeys.length; i++) {
    if(typeof receiver[giverkeys[i]] != typeof giver[giverkeys[i]]) {
      receiver[giverkeys[i]] = giver[giverkeys[i]];
    }
    if(receiver[giverkeys[i]] != giver[giverkeys[i]]) {
      receiver[giverkeys[i]] = giver[giverkeys[i]];
    }
  }
}
fillBlanks(userCacheOptions.monit, defaultOptions.monit);
console.log(userCacheOptions.monit);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over the keys and check for objects and call the function recursive with the new objects to check. If a value is missing, then set it to the default value.

```js
function setDefault(user, def) {
    Object.keys(def).forEach(function (k) {
        if (def[k] !== null && typeof def[k] === 'object') {
            if (!(k in user)) {
                user[k] = {};
            }
            setDefault(user[k], def[k]);
            return;
        }
        if (!(k in user)) {
            user[k] = def[k];
        }
    });
}

var defaultOptions = { monit: { map: { googleMap: false }, vehiclesList: { rightSide: false, number: true, driver: true, note: true, }, vehicleCloud: { speed: true, date: true, alarms: true, fuelsCloud: true }, driverCloud: true } },
    userCacheOptions = { monit: { vehiclesList: { rightSide: false, number: false, driver: false }, vehicleCloud: { speed: true, date: true, alarms: true, fuelsCloud: true }, } };

setDefault(userCacheOptions, defaultOptions);

console.log(userCacheOptions);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this job as follows; It recursively iterates and modifies the `userCacheOptions` object at place.

```js
var defaultOptions = {
         monit : {
            map:{
                googleMap: false
            },
            vehiclesList: {
                rightSide: false,
                number: true,
                driver: true,
                note: true,
            },
            vehicleCloud: {
                speed: true,
                date: true,
                alarms: true,
                fuelsCloud: true
            },
            driverCloud: true
           }
     };

var userCacheOptions = {
        monit : {
                // Missing map options
            vehiclesList: {
                rightSide: false,
                number: false,
                driver: false
                // Missing note option
            },
            vehicleCloud: {
                speed: true,
                date: true,
                alarms: true,
                fuelsCloud: true
            },
            // Missing driverCloud option
         }
    };

function restoreMissing(def,obj){
  Object.keys(def).map(k => (typeof def[k] === "object" &&
                             typeof obj[k] === "object") ? restoreMissing(def[k],obj[k])
                                                         : !obj[k] && (obj[k] = def[k]));
  return obj;
}

console.log(restoreMissing(defaultOptions,userCacheOptions))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the pattern that you want to follow, you just add the appropriate actions for each check.

```
if(!(defaultOptions.equals(userCacheOptions))){

        //check for userCacheOptions if the value is set
        //if its not set then set it as you want

        if(!(userCacheOptions.getGoogleMap().isSet())){
            userCacheOptions.setGoogleMap("whatever you want to set");
        }

        //same each variable etc
    }
```

Comment: I needed more automatic solution :)